# MSDN documentation error? "If the procedure is Shared, all its local variables are automatically shared. This includes the Static variables."

Tags: .net, vb.net, msdn

I was reviewing the MSDN documentation on VB.Net's little-used [Static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) keyword for local variables. My question is **not** about how Static works (I personally plan to avoid using it as it seems like it could cause grief to future programmers who don't notice the side-effects.) **My question is about this statement in the docs**:

> **The behavior of any local variable depends on whether it is declared
>   in a Shared procedure. If the procedure is Shared, all its local
>   variables are automatically shared. This includes the Static
>   variables. There is only one copy of such a variable for the whole
>   application.**

This seems to imply that all local variables in a Shared Sub would behave like Static variables -- they would keep their values across separate calls. But I knew this wasn't the case, and I wrote a little test program to prove it:

```
Class TestSharedSub

    Shared Sub Main()
        Test()
        Test()
        Test()
        Console.Write("Press any key to continue...") : Console.ReadKey()
        ' Output:
        ' 1, 1
        ' 2, 1
        ' 3, 1
    End Sub

    Shared Sub Test()
        Dim iNormal As Integer
        Static iStatic As Integer
        iNormal += 1
        iStatic += 1
        Console.WriteLine(iStatic & ", " & iNormal)
    End Sub

End Class
```

So can anyone interpret the above statement for me in a way that makes sense? Or is this a bug in the documentation? It's been there since the VS 2005 version of the docs and is still present in the Visual Studio 11 version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's talking nonsense. It continues being utterly broken in the next paragraph:

> If the procedure is not Shared, its local variables are instance variables.

Local variables aren't instance variables...

Whoever wrote that page appears not to understand local variables at all. Goodness knows what they'd make of recursion. Mind you, it *starts off* reasonably:

> Normally, a local variable in a procedure ceases to exist as soon as the procedure stops.

... but that statement is clearly in contradiction to the later ones. *Sigh.*

I suggest you file a bug on [Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com).

Answer (score 3):

That particular piece of documentation is wrong.  Local variables declared in a `Shared` method are no different than locals declared in a non-Shared method.  The only behavior difference for locals comes into play with they are declared with the `Static` modifier.

I'll alert the appropriate team about it.

**EDIT**

The team in charge of the documentation was alerted and will be correcting the documentation in the very near future.

Comment: Cool, thanks Jared! I awarded the answer to Jon since he got in just a couple minutes before you. But I appreciate you putting in a word for me. I think I'll still file a bug report on Connect though to get the ball rolling: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/730944/msdn-documentation-error-if-the-procedure-is-shared-all-its-local-variables-are-automatically-shared-this-includes-the-static-variables.

Comment: @JordanRieger i'll edit my answer with any additional information i find out.

Comment: They have updated the docs for VS 2012 and 2012, but not 2008 or 2005. I posted another comment on the Connect bug report asking them to fix the 2008 and 2005 docs too.