# SQL Server decimal scale length - can be or has to be?

Tags: sql-server, decimal, scale, precision

I have really simply question about `DECIMAL` (and maybe `NUMERIC`) type in SQL Server 2008 R2.

**MSDN said:**

> (scale)
>   The maximum number of decimal digits that can be stored to the right of the decimal point. Scale must be a value from 0 through p.

I understand this following way:

- if I have `DECIMAL(10, 5)` - I am able to store 12345.12345 or 12345678.91.
- if I have `DECIMAL(5, 5)` - I can have 12345 or 1234.5 or 1.2345, etc...

Is it clear?

But I got this error message:

```
SELECT CAST(2.8514 AS DECIMAL(5,5))
```

> Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.

I thought 5,5 means I can have up to 5 digits and up to 5 CAN BE right of the decimal point.

As I tried:

```
SELECT CAST(12.851 AS DECIMAL(6,5)) - overflows too
```

**however**

```
SELECT CAST(1.23456 AS DECIMAL(6,5)) - is OK.
```

So what's the truth?

`DECIMAL(a,b)` says that I can have up to a digits and JUST b of them are right to the decimal point (and there rest a-b to the left to the dec. point)?

I'm really confused about statement in doc which is copied everywhere. Please take a while and explain me this simple thing.

Lot of thanks!

Comment: `DECIMAL(5,5)` means: total of 5 digits, 5 of which are **after** the decimal point - so basically this is not a valid number... `DECIMAL(10,5)` means: total of 10 digits, 5 of which **after** the decimal point (and therefore 5 before the decimal point, too). It's not a ***CAN BE*** after the decimal point - it's a ***ARE AFTER*** the decimal point specification

Comment: @marc_s I believe that's exactly why the OP is confused: the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) only uses the word "can", so it's not really clear that decimal(5,5) 'reserves' 5 digits after the decimal point, whether you 'use' them or not. Perhaps it's obvious to more mathematically inclined people, of course (I'm not one of those people).

Comment: @Pondlife you are actually right about the documentation being confusing. Back in 2013, I submitted a bug report to MSDN, and they changed it to the wording I suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207222/decimal-10-9-variable-cant-hold-the-number-50-sql-server-2008.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The easiest way to think of it (for me) is that precision is the total number of digits, *of which* scale is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point. So `DECIMAL(p,s)` means `p-s` digits to the left of the point, and `s` digits to the right of the point.

That explains all the conversion errors you're seeing: the `2.8514` cannot be `decimal(5,5)` because `p-s = 0`; `12.851` cannot be `decimal(6,5)` because `p-s = 1` and so on.