# Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric for Decimal(25,12)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I know the question is a duplicate, but I am not able to find a solution to my problem below:

```
                SELECT
                CAST(747448809352908.49434500000 AS  Decimal(25,12)) AS [Value]
```

This is the value I am getting from one of my calculations. I am trying to insert into a Table with Value column designed as Decimal(25,12). With a value as above I am getting an overflow error.

Please assist.
The problem being I cannot update the settings of the column. Therefore I need to fit into the the column.

I cannot can I??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decimal (10,9) variable can't hold the number 50 (SQL Server 2008)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207222/decimal-10-9-variable-cant-hold-the-number-50-sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your total length of value is not matched with your data type. you are assigning `Decimal(25,12)` but length more than 25, actually 27

```
SELECT CAST('747448809352908.49434500000' AS  Decimal(27,12)) AS [Value]
```

In SQL Server, decimal and numeric are numeric data types that have fixed precision and scale.

For a decimal(5,2) variable, it can only hold three (5-2) digits before the decimal point and two digits after the decimal point. However, “1234” has four digits before the decimal point so it exceeds the precision and the error occurs.

The same issue happens if you assign an integer value 1234 to the decimal(5,2).
[decimal and numeric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187746.aspx)

Comment: Looks like I have no other option that to increase the column size. Thanks

Comment: @DarshanBI-DW if last zeros(00000) are not useful then you can remove it so your objective will satisfy but if needed

Answer (score 1):

Your number is too big for `decimal(25, 12)`. Count with me - there's 15 digits left of the decimal point, and your precision is 25. 12 of those 25 is for decimals, so you're left with 13. 13 is less than 15 -> arithmetic overflow.

`decimal` is *not* a floating point number. Its precision and scale is fixed - you defined that your number has 13 digits left of the decimal point, and twelve right. That's all you have to work with. The fact that some of the decimals are zero is irrelevant - `decimal` can't "shift" the decimal point at will. It's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

tinka answer is correct but here is explanation

the length of this `747448809352908.49434500000` is 27 so in DECIMAL should contain the maximum length of the number , so the error because you specify 25 , the number 12 is the number after the comma `49434500000` whic is 11.

Answer (score 0):

The number you entering is too big. You might reffer this [link]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx if you change the number below 11 in place of 12 then you will get some answer. so try to decrease number.